# I created a list using button clicks, now i want to display that list using a different button

Tags: c#, string, list

How do I show a list in a message box using a button click?

Comment: What difference does it make whether the list was created *using button clicks* or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you're using winforms, you can double-click on your button, and do like so in the event handler

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<string> strlst;
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        foreach(string s in strlst)
        {
            sb.AppendLine(s);
        }

        MessageBox.Show(sb.ToString());
    }
```

Comment: Ok that works. I tried to copy this code and edit it for another button as well. However when i did that and ran my program the new button would display an empty message box and the original button displayed both lists?

Comment: @user1860514 do your lists have content in them?

Answer (score 0):

You need to append the list to a string but join them using the new line, it is a quick way instead of iterating over the list.

```
String message = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, list);
MessageBox.Show(message, "MessageList", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
```